# How to grab the h3 text within a div

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

My website HTML has the following:

[image]

To grab the H3 text (SOME TEXT) as a variable in Tag Manager - when a user clicks on the div class "c-card c-card--primary  c-parkcard " I think I need to use a DOM Element variable

[image]

But it's not returning the text.
Should the Element Selector be:

```
.c-card.c-card--primary.c-card__body.u-h6.c-card__title
```

However, it returns a null value in Tag Manager

Comment: The two dots are invalid. Use only one. and unless you have just one h3 in your page, using the header classname would be a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to create a custom JS variable that when the image was clicked on would find the "c-card c-card--primary c-parkcard " div (9 parents up) and then go back down to find the h3 element by class and then return the text:

```
function(){
var z = {{Click Element}}.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
.getElementsByClassName('u-h6 c-card__title')[0].innerText;
return z;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> use of `getElementsByClass` is as simple as:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$content_node=$dom->getElementByClass("c-card__body");

$div_a_class_nodes=getElementsByClass($content_node, 'h3', 'u-h6 c-card__title');
```

Comment: in Tag Manager, JS variables need a return value

Answer (score 0):

You have set "h3" as "attribute name. "h3" is not an attribute (but the name of the tag). You do not want to set an attribute name at all, because you do not want to return the value of an attribute, but the innerText of the tag, and that is the default behaviour anyway.

If you use a DOM variable this will return the first instance on the page. If your selector matches several DOM nodes, you will still just get the first one, regardless if what the user clicks. If you expect this to update depending on the clicked element, you should rather use the {{Click Text}} variable (a built-in variable that you might have to enable first).

Chances are that the actual click element is not the h3, but the nested link inside, but that does not really change things for you (as in both cases the innerText will be the contained texted nodes, which in this case is the same).

Comment: My Element Selector is now {{Click Text}}.u-h6.c-card__title but only grabs the first instance of H3.

Comment: I did not mean to use the click text as a selector. The value of the click text is the innerText of the element that was last clicked on, you do not need any additional variables.